# Strange file being created automatically after installing a Python library

Tags: python, namespaces, package, cython, namespace-package

I have a Python library that depends on a C library, so I'm using Cython to deal with it. While I've managed to wrap the library and it's ready for installation, I've been facing a strange problem (note: for the sake of non-advertising I'm not using the name of the library).

I have the following directory structure:

```
package/
       setup.py
       library/
              __init__.py
              module/
                    lib.py
                    _lib.pyx
```

The `setup.py` is supposed to convert `_lib.pyx` into `_lib.so`, which can be easily imported by Python. Also, `library.module` is supposed to be installed as a namespace package, so `lib.__init__.py` contains the single line of code required by PEP420.

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

But when I do:

```
python setup.py install
```

and after checking the `.egg` created I find a `_lib.py` created inside `module` with the following lines in it

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'_lib.so')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

While `_lib.py` is present along with `_lib.so`, as soon as `lib.py` imports `_lib`, it imports the _lib.py file rather than importing `_lib.so` which is the actual Python wrapper of the C library.

I'd like to know why `_lib.py` is being created and how I can avoid it.

Comment: What exactly does *"the work is not possible to continue"* mean?

Comment: Sorry. That means, `lib.py` needs imports `_lib` module because that is the Python wrapper of the C library. But as soon as `import _lib` is done, it imports the `_lib.py` file rather than importing `_lib.so`.

Comment: Please edit that information into the question.

Comment: It seems cython creates it, but I'm having a problem with these files in cx_freeze ("resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip"). Did you run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now clear that the *strange* file being created with the same name as `.so` file, is not creating any problem. Infact that's necessary for the tighter integration with the `.so` module. So, It is automatically created while installing the file.